# play and pause button is not working in carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am performing carousel play and pause using jquery and javascript in bootstrap. I have written the code but not getting where I missed.
Here is the full code which might let u catch my mistake.
The problem is that the buttons for play and pause are in the scope of carousel and the behaviour a button normally gives is not the same here.
For the current situation, the buttons are positioned below the prev button and performing the same action which prev is performing i.e. showing the previous image.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                                 src="img/uthappizza.png" alt="uthappizza">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h2>Uthappizza<span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">$4.99</span></h2>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">A unique combination of Indian Uthappam</p>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                                 src="img/buffet.png" alt="buffet">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h2>Weekend Grand Buffet<span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span></h2>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads.</p>                                
                           </div>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid"
                                 src="img/alberto.png" alt="alberto">
                           <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                               <h2>Alberto Somayya</h2>
                                <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience.</p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="btn-group" id="carouselButton">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-pause">
                            <span class="fa fa-pause"></span>
                        </button>&nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carousel-play">
                            <span class="fa fa-play"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
                <h3>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm order-sm-first col-md">
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail align-self-center" src="img/uthappizza.png" alt="uthappizza">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="mt-0">Uthappizza<span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">$4.99</span></h2>
                        <p>A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                <h3>This Month's Promotions</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm col-md">
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex order-sm-last mr-3 img-thumbnail align-self-center" src="img/buffet.png" alt="buffet">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="mt-0">Weekend Grand Buffet<span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span></h2>
                        <p>Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row row-content align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-3">
                <h3>Meet our Culinary Specialists</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm col-md order-sm-first">
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail align-self-center" src="img/alberto.png" alt="alberto">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="mt-0">Alberto Somayya<span class="badge badge-danger">Exclusive</span><span class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">$4.99</span></h2>
                        <h4>Executive Chef</h4>
                        <p>Award winning three-star Michelin chef with wide International experience.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#mycarousel').carousel({ interval : 2000 });
            $('#carousel-pause').click(function(){
                $('#mycarousel').carousel('pause');
            });
            $('#carousel-play').click(function(){
                $('#mycarousel').carousel('cycle');
            });
        });
    </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Proper Behaviour of Carousel play and pause.

Comment: [It seems to work for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/s69h37nr/) What specifically is going wrong? Do you get any JavaScript errors in your browser console?

Comment: Whenever I click on any of the buttons then it shows me the next slide. I can see that my buttons are not getting clicked. I am not getting any errors.

Comment: It might help to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue. Have you included the jQuery and Bootstrap libraries?

Comment: Removing jquery code it is behaving same going to the next slide. when the button is clicked it shows some focused behaviour but here it is not doing anything like that, it is working like a label.

Comment: These two buttons are working same as prev works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce that problem with the code provided.

Comment: okay! First of all Thanks for giving your valuable time to me. But now I am editing my Post with all of my code. If you feel to correct that then It would be a pleasure for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196289/discussion-between-orbit-and-showdev).

Answer (score 0):

yeah dude, i also had the problem while doing a course from coursera. It is not the problem with jquery. Set the "z-index" of "carouselButton" to 2 or higher and it should work

Answer (score 0):

After going through your script i discover you opt out an important detail in your code that is you didn't add pause: false after interval:2000. so your script code should have been presented this way.

```html
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mycarousel").carousel( { interval: 2000, pause: false } );
            $("#carousel-pause").click(function(){
                $("#mycarousel").carousel('pause');
            });
            $("#carousel-play").click(function(){
                $("#mycarousel").carousel('cycle');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

or you can make use of this

```html
    <script>
        $('#mycarousel').carousel({
            interval: 1500,
            pause: false
        });
        $('#carousel-pause').click(function() {
            $('#mycarousel').carousel('pause');
        });
        $('#carousel-play').click(function() {
            $('#mycarousel').carousel('cycle');
        });
    </script>
```

either ways your code will be up and running fine when you click the pause or play button

Answer (score 0):

Yeah...set `z-index: 1;` to `carouselButton` ...it will definitely work.